# Where can I get all the info on development for Samsung Devices?

Tags: android, bada

Too many devices and variations for targeting a certain devices.
I wanna have some bird-eye view of mobile development at a certain forum.

Motorola, for instance, has Motodev as Nokia has Forum Nokia, then how'bout Samsung??
Samsung has already bada Developers and Samsung Mobile Innovator, but those are not supporting a holistic view of whole devices.

Comment: Bird eye views are generally kept internal to the company. It depends on what you want to do.[Here is an FAQ](http://developer.samsung.com/faq.do) If there is any specific technical help you need let me know.

Comment: oh, Samsung has already one http://developer.samsung.com as you said. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Im posting the comment as an answer because unanswered questions get deleted. [Here is the link to the official](http://developer.samsung.com/) samsung site for developers. Unfortunately its rather limited. Hopefully samsung will be more dev friendly in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Official resources : http://developer.bada.com (for native development) and http://innovator.samsungmobile.com (for widget development)

Unofficial resources: http://forums.badadev.com and http://ask.badadev.com/questions/